# How to use DOMXPath query to get area shapes

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

Current PHP:

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($htmlsrc);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $tags = $xpath->query('//div/map/area');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        var_dump(trim($tag->nodeValue));
    }
```

Which obviously is not correct. I have a variable that holds file_get_contents of a file which has a few (about 8 thousand) of these:

```
<area shape="poly" alt="" coords="500,327,464,349,467,385,478,400,492,394,500,356" href="1880314600" title="" />
```

I'm trying to collect $coords and $href so I can put these in a database instead of a file but I just cant catch on to how to use xpath. Sorry I do not have a correct answer to "What have you tried?" I have tried a ton of stuff, I simply cannot understand this (or regex for that matter).

**EDIT**
For the comments:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    var_dump($xpath);
    $tags = $xpath->query('//div/map/area');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        var_dump($tag->getAttribute('coords'));
    }
```

The first var_dump() shows: (edited because there are tons of them)

```
object(DOMXPath)#2985 (1) { ["document"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" } string(47) "500,327,464,349,467,385,478,400,492,394,500,356" string(47) "559,310,530,314,532,394,543,389,561,367,561,351" string(63) "613,369,586,343,575,343,575,369,584,394,618,402,638,398,629,371" string(47) "523,431,501,438,498,451,537,468,550,464,550,447" string(39) "525,464,510,460,507,466,518,471,523,469"
```

However the second var_dump does not return anything. Why is the first xpath dump only showing coords? Further more I am not even puting in a query at that point...

Comment: `var_dump($tag->getAttribute('coords'));`?

Comment: I must have done something wrong, I am not getting any result from var_dump not even NULL. Let me make sure I am not doing something stupid first before I continue this.

Comment: do a `var_dump($htmlsrc)` to make sure you get what you're expecting as input, then make sure that DOM actually was able to load/parse that html - it's **VERY** picky about malformed html.

Comment: Please check the edit in the post. It is returning all of the coords without a xpath query...which I don't mind but I would also like the href="";

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't see it was 2 objects. I'm stupid. Thank you @PeeHaa if you'd like to add that as an answer I would be happy to mark as answered. Exactly what I needed. I was too busy over-complicating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the coordinates (or any other attribute for that matter) you [can simply do](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php):

```
var_dump($tag->getAttribute('coords'));
```

If you also want to get the `href` attribute you can simply do:

```
var_dump([
    'coords' => $tag->getAttribute('coords'),
    'href'   => $tag->getAttribute('href'),
]);
```